# iadd in python class

Tags: python, class, addition

I created a class and I refined the add function but for some reason it is not working correctly. This is what I have:

```
def __iadd__(self,thing): 

    try: 
        tester=True
        for y in thing:
            if type(y) != type('f'):
                tester=False
        for j in thing:
            self.listt.append(j)
        return self
    except(tester==False):
        return ValueError
```

Whenever I do:

```
f=class('ab')

f += [4]
```

it is supposed to return a `ValueError` because I am adding something that is not a string but for some reason it is appending the int even though its not supposed too.

Comment: you are using the `try/except` block wrong. if you want it to go into the except block, you need to `raise` an error

Comment: all `except(tester==False):` is going to give you is a `catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed` if you ever raise an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __iadd__(self, thing): 
    for y in thing:
        if not isinstance(y, str):
            raise ValueError
    for j in thing:
        self.listt.append(j)
    return self
```